# Is it possible to end the okta session from Azure?

Tags: azure-active-directory, logout, idp, usersession, single-logout

Okta will always gives the previous guest user session when I try to login with another user. Is it possible to end the okta session from azure?

In my iOS application, I introduced Okta as an External Identity by using SAML. All of this is functioning, but when I attempt to log out a guest user, the user will leave Azure, but their Okta session will remain open. As a result, Okta will always gives the previous guest user when I try to login with another user. Is it possible to end the okta session?

Please accept my gratitude for any assistance or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would suggest reaching out to the Okta Support Team would help here, to see if their engineers and community can take a closer look into your issue.
For reference you can refer to okta documentation related to sign out behavior.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1089192/is-it-possible-to-end-the-okta-session-from-azure.html